# char* pointer array not incrementing in C

Tags: arrays, c, char

I'm trying to write a program that reads a file, prints what's in the file, add the contents of said file to an array, print from the array and then write to a file using the contents of the array.

My problem is when I try and print to the file, the array only prints the last entry in my char* array. Why does this happen?

Here's the problem code:

```
    char name[100];
    int age = 0;
    float bBalance = 0;

    char* namesArray[100];
    int ageArray[100];
    float floatArray[100];

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) 
    {
        namesArray[i] = (char*)malloc(100);
    }


    fptr = fopen("NTD.txt", "r");

    int lPtr = 1;

    if (fptr == NULL)
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        while (fscanf(fptr, "%99[^ ,], %d, %f", name, &age, &bBalance) != EOF)
        {
            namesArray[lPtr] = name;
            ageArray[lPtr] = age;
            floatArray[lPtr] = bBalance;

            printf("%s \n", namesArray[lPtr]);
            printf("%d \n", ageArray[lPtr]);
            printf("%f \n", floatArray[lPtr]);

            lPtr++;
        }

        fclose(fptr);
    }


    fptr = fopen("writeTo.txt", "w");

    if (fptr == NULL)
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        int i = 1;

        while (lPtr != 0)
        {
            fprintf(fptr, "%s,%d,%f \n",namesArray[i], ageArray[i], floatArray[i]);

            i++;
        }

        fclose(fptr);
    }
```

This is what the final file should look like:

```
Jane,50,420.69

Sam,20,50.00

Fabian,21,682.22

Zac,35,40000.00

Gabe,12,0.00

Shy,29,12.00

Charlot,99,0.00

Gen,15,64592.68

Guy,98,20000.00

Bill,60,1000000.00
```

This is what it actually looks like:

```
Bill,50,420.690002 

Bill,20,50.000000 

Bill,21,682.219971 

Bill,35,40000.000000 

Bill,12,0.000000 

Bill,29,12.000000 

Bill,99,0.000000 

Bill,15,64592.679688 

Bill,98,20000.000000 

Bill,60,1000000.000000
```

If you need anything else, please let me know

Comment: `fscanf` reads all names into the same `char name[100];` buffer, then `namesArray[lPtr] = name;` saves a *pointer* to that buffer in the array (and overwrites the pointer previously allocated). When you `fprintf` you get what was last read into the `name` buffer. User `strcpy` instead to copy each name.

Comment: What sets `lPtr` between `while (lPtr != 0)` and then end of that loop? (one of those things where the scenery never changes....) Change the loop to `while (lPtr--)` In C, there is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: WRONG: `namesArray[lPtr] = name`;  CORRECT: `strcpy(namesArray[lPtr], name);`  You can't just "assign" strings in C.  You need to COPY the string, with a function like [strcpy()](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy)

Answer (score 3):

> namesArray[lPtr] = name;

Here is your problem. You make every element in `namesArray` point to `name`. `name` gets a new value read into it for each line, and in the end, it contains the last value read. All of the storage that you `malloc`'d in advance is leaked (it's still allocated, but you no longer hold any pointers to it, which means you can't use it and you can't free it).

You wanted to do `strncpy(namesArray[lPtr], name, 100)` to *copy the characters* from `name` to the already-existing `char *` in `namesArray`, instead of using `=` which copies the pointer itself, not the pointed-to values.

Comment: Thank you Hobbs, you fixed my problem :D